# Is it possible to emulate Tk receive in tkinter?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I have an application that supports communicating to other **Tk** applications using the `send` method.  In **Tcl/Tk** it's easy to call a user subroutine in one **Tk** app by calling `send()` from another **Tk** app and specifying the receiving app and subroutine `name` and `args`. In **Perl** it's possible to do the same with a little more work (overriding the definition of `Tk::Receive` to act on an incoming message from another app's `send` method).

Does anyone know to use **tkinter** to receive external messages coming from **Tk** `send`?  I'd like to have a subroutine that is called to process incoming messages while in `mainloop()`.

Comment: I'm not in a position to test this, but looks like you can register a Python function to be callable from the Tcl/Tk side via `someWidget.tk.createcommand(name, func)` - if the Tk `send` mechanism is supported on your platform, then the name you registered should be a valid target for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @jasonharper, the following worked in python 3.6:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

def some_func(*args):
    print("Got args: " + ",".join(args))

# Create a command called my_func that calls some_func
root.tk.createcommand("my_func", some_func)

root.mainloop()
```

E.g. if I did `send tk my_func hey` from another Tk app, assuming the default tkinter appname `tk`, I would see `Got args: hey` from the above code